# Should we avoid the use of internal Tridion codenames

Tags: discussion

When a new project is worked on in Tridion R&D, they use internal code-names. Occasionally, these names leak out and start getting used more generally in the community. An example of this was "Anguilla", the code name for the framework that underpins the GUI.

Using these names is probably very cool, but it runs the risk that we exclude people who are new to Tridion, and who only know things by their official documented names.

Yes - there will be grey areas... but shouldn't we try to stick to publicly available naming conventions wherever possible?

Comment: What would you propose as an alternative for Anguilla? I am not aware of a pubic name for it

Comment: For practical purposes, posts about Anguilla are about GUI extensions. Sure - if we're pedantic, Anguilla is the entire framework, but I don't think that distinction will be called into question.

Comment: Would we assume the technical or API terms if there's a choice? For example, I believe the Business Connector 2 is synonymous (or maybe just the marketing term for) with the Core Service. I suspect we'd prefer `core-service` as the tag.

Comment: Don't know anyone that calls it BC2, and core service is what it's called in some of the documentation, but you have a point.

Answer (score 4):

For tagging questions I think using the documented naming convention is the way to go.

I would say the same should generally be true for the actual text of questions/answers with the caveat specific terms/names generally used and accepted by the community should probably not, by themselves, be a trigger for edits to questions/answers.

In the specific case of 'Anguilla' I'm not sure what my position is, is that a code name or an offical name? In our 2011 training last year the SDL trainer made extensive use of the name 'Anguilla' when describing the GUI extensibility framework for Tridion (although we were 5 days into the training before I realized she was saying Anguilla and not Angular.)

Comment: Anguilla certainly /was/ an internal code name. (R&D used the names of Caribbean islands during the development of 2011). Yes - you see Anguilla in a couple of places, but AFAIK it was never an official brand. Maybe SDL can solve this for us by officially naming it Anguilla. Why not?

Comment: @DominicCronin I was going to say maybe we can bribe Nuno or Bart to create a Synonym (you need 1250 rep to create synonyms and both of them are above that rep at this time) pointing anguilla at either the cme or cme-extensions but it looks like Bart already has already added a pending synonmym for anquilla pointing it to cme.

Comment: Yes - sure - you could make a synonym. This question is as much about the way we want to encourage people to use the site. So perhaps in the FAQ, we should say, please use the "official" name of a feature or API if you know it. My point is rather that this ends up being a kind of "insider slang" that only serves to exclude newer people.

Comment: @DominicCronin Understood. If you have any suggestions on wording/where in the FAQ we should add this let me know. The only section of the FAQ we can edit is the 'What kinds of questions can I ask here ?' section. My current suggested text for this section is located here: http://meta.tridion.stackexchange.com/a/8/39